# How to display Euro sign in verbatim mode?

Tags: symbols, verbatim

I need to display the Dollar and Euro sign in verbatim mode. This is the code I got:

```
\begin{verbatim}
fr_FR: 123 456,78 €
de_DE: 123.456,78 €
en_US: $ 123,456.78
\end{verbatim}
```

It works with the Dollar sign, but not with the Euro sign. I tried escaping but that didn't work either. Any thoughts?

I reduced the document to the following lines. And there is still no Euro sign:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,compsoc]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
fr_FR: 123 456,78 €
de_DE: 123.456,78 €
en_US: $ 123,456.78
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Eclipse also shows an Error:

> Keyboard character used is undefined \end{verbatim} (followed by: )

Comment: Are you sure your file is saved as UTF-8 encoded? The error message seems to point to a different encoding

Comment: Yes, you were right. It was encoded `Cp1252`. I changed it to UTF-8 and now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Euro symbol in the standard fonts, so `textcomp` is required. However, the glyph in the European Modern fonts is ugly and wrong; with Latin Modern it's better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
fr_FR: 123 456,78 €
de_DE: 123.456,78 €
en_US: $ 123,456.78
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There's nothing to do other than loading `textcomp` if you use `IEEEtran`, because in this case Courier is employed.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
fr_FR: 123 456,78 €
de_DE: 123.456,78 €
en_US: $ 123,456.78
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use the `cmex10` option to `amsmath`: it's only for compatibility with *very* old TeX distributions.

Comment: if I add this to the other `\usepackage` declarations, the whole template gets changed. Can I use the package only for the verbatim block?

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes What font packages are you using?

Comment: I am a absolute newbie in Latex, and don't know how to answer your question :'-( I added all `\usepackage` declarations to my answer. Does this help?

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes That's good.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Now the template remains the same. But the Euro sign is still not shown.